# Url rewrite [Long url to short]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm developing CMS and want to make template system. So I could have multiple themes, like Wordpress has. But I have problem with urls.
My question is how to rewrite this url:

> http://example.com/themes/mytheme/post.php?slug=some-post-title

to something like this:

> http://example.com/post/some-post-title

So point is to cut that part of **themes/mytheme**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slug=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/post.php post/%1? [NC]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

The `RewriteCond` detects the query string and allows for a back-substitution with `%1` in the `RewriteRule`.

`^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/` matches the first two folders.

The `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` is an empty query string so that the GET variables won't be passed through.

`[NC]` means case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: I did the same but does not work.. error 404 The requested URL /post/nesto was not found on this server.

Comment: So you want the rewrite to go in the opposite direction?

Comment: I did like this 

RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/?$ themes/mytheme/post.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

but I need 'mytheme' to be dynamic, some pattern

Comment: Where are you going to get the theme from in a htaccess rule if it isn't contained in the URL or the query string?

Comment: I have folders public_html/themes/SOMEtheme

And my url now is like .../themes/sometheme/post.php?slug=xxx
And I want .../post/xxx

Comment: I made  ^post/(.*)/?$ themes/mytheme/post.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

And it's works but it is static for one theme name..

Comment: What determines which theme URL to rewrite to? It has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77744/discussion-between-lazar-bulatovic-and-samgak).